# Swing send an event programmatically

Tags: events, swing

How can I do to create a custom event and send it programmatically to a
component?

E.g. If I had a `JButton` and wanted to create an `ActionEvent` or a `MouseEvent` and than send it as
if an user had pressed on it which code I'd to use?

The following code not work:

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Click...");

MouseAdapter my = new MouseAdapter()
{
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
   {
      area.setText("Button clicked!!!");
   }
};
btn.addMouseListener(my);

MouseEvent me = new MouseEvent(btn, MouseEvent.BUTTON1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, false);
btn.dispatchEvent(my);
```

Comment: Generating an event is a bit nasty. Are you sure there isn't another solution that will solve your problem? In the case of the JButton you can call button.getModel().setPressed(true).

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example you can simply call `AbstractButton#doClick`.

If you need to create synthetic events for the general case, make sure fill in all fields that a real `AWTEvent` would have, since the event handlers may take them for granted.

Comment: @xdevel2000: What specific event do you want to generate?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800840/sending-keypresses-to-jtextfield for an example.

Comment: Ok, I understand that I must use dispatchEvent on the component I want the event be sent. I tried to use it on a JButton but it does not work...look at the example I posted into the modified question. What's wrong?

Comment: Aside from the obvious typo (`btn.dispatchEvent(me)` instead of `my`), your code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call the `dispatchEvent` method with the Event as an argument