# Sending keypresses to JTextField

Tags: java, events, swing, keyboard-events

I'm trying to simulate text input into a `JTextField`. I've got a 1 char long string containing the letter I want to add and I run:

```
receiver.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(this,
  KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, 0,
  this.shifted?KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK:0,
  KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED, text.charAt(0)));
```

But this doesn't seem to change the contents at all. What am I missing here?

Comment: Works for me. Can you post some code that demonstrates this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a virtual keyboard to me :-)

Almost the exact same code does work for me. I would suggest the following:

1. Pass the target `JTextField` (in your case, `receiver`) as the `source` parameter to the `KeyEvent` constructor, i.e.:

   ```
   receiver.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(receiver,
       KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, System.currentTimeMillis(),
       modifiers, KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED, keyChar);
   ```
2. Ensure your target `JTextField` has the focus.

**Edit:**

Just to verify the above suggestion, I tested this snippet of code:

```
Frame frame = new Frame();
TextField text = new TextField();
frame.add(text);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);

text.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(frame,
        KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, 0,
        0,
        KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED, 'H'));
```

This does not work, however if the last line is modified as follows (target component as the `source` parameter of the `KeyEvent` constructor), it works fine:

```
text.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(text,
        KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, 0,
        0,
        KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED, 'H'));
```

Comment: Yes, it is a virtual keyboard and no I don't have the focus on the text field. I'll try this out as soon as I get back to the project.

Comment: Make sure to check the other suggestion as well (pass the target component as `source` of the `KeyEvent`). I had this same problem in a project of mine.

Comment: Also, for future reference, I didn't need the focus. Setting the text field as the event source and adding proper time was enough.

Comment: Good. I believe the component *must* be focusable, though, even if it does not currently have the focus. This is not an issue for standard components, though.